# Automator Service: Parent of input from files or folders

Tags: applescript, automator, services

I cannot find *any* information on this, so I hope somebody with experience can fill in the gap.

I am writing a simple Automator Service, and I can’t get past the first step.

- The script is a `Service`
- Service receives selected `files or folders` in `Finder.app`
- `Run AppleScript`

The script is

```
on run {input,parameters}
    set test to container of input -- Can’t make container into type reference.
    display dialog test as string
    return input
end run
```

The `input` parameter has the selected file or folder, and all I want to do at this stage is to get the parent folder of the selected item. Everything I try, which is from countless *near* solutions on the web fail in this, telling me that I can’t make the container into a reference.

I have no idea what I should be doing, and I can’t find any information on this.

How can I get the parent folder using Automator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly-brace portion of `on run {input, parameters}` creates a *list* and as such you need to address *input* as a *list*.

The following example assumes only one file or folder gets passed to the Service:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        set thePath to POSIX path of (container of (item 1 of input))
    end tell
    return thePath
end run
```

Can your Service receive more then one file or folder at a time? ... If yes, then you'll need to incorporate the *code* below.

The following example assumes multiple files or folders gets passed to the Service:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set pathList to {}
    repeat with itemNum from 1 to count of input
        tell application "System Events"
            copy POSIX path of (container of (item itemNum of input)) to end of pathList
        end tell
    end repeat
    return pathList
end run
```

---

Reference: [Getting the path of the parent folder of a file?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1531881?tstart=0)

Comment: I didn’t realise that `input` was a list. Thanks for your solutions. I have turned the first one to a service to get the parent path, and modified the second to give me a list of full path names. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work. Returns "Can't get container of "[selected file name].